# Well-definedness of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We define $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{x} := \{\overline{a}\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}: \exists \overline{c} $ such that $\overline{ac} = \overline{1}\}$.  I was then asked to prove $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{x} = \{ \overline{a}\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}: gcd(a,n)=1 \} $.  I was able to complete the problem, however they also noted that it was important to check that the latter set was well-defined - why is this the case?  I thought we only had to check well-definedness for functions.  Is it because we are defining a set of objects with respect to its representatives, which may not necessarily be unique (this makes some sense to me, but my understanding of this is not concrete yet).

Can someone clarify for me the reasoning for checking well-definedness and when to check it, and perhaps help me to better understand this.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to define $\{\bar a \in \mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z |p(\bar a) \}$ with $p(\bar a)$ a predicate defined in terms of a representative. Just like with functions, you need to show that the truth value of the predicate $p(\bar a)$ does not depend on the representative used.

Answer (score 1):

SolubleFish’s answer is correct, but a little brief. To elaborate a bit, $\bar a$ is one of many different ways to write the same element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and the definition’s condition depends on $a$. Is the condition independent of which $a$ you used to write an element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Here’s an example of a “definition” that is not well-defined. Let $F=\{{a\over b}\in\mathbb{Q}\,\vert\,a\text{ is even}\}$.